# Procedural Code vs OOP code

Tags: programming-languages, programming-practices

I've finished a project in PHP of 13000+ lines in Procedural Style [because I'm very familiar with that, though I know OOP], and the project is running perfectly.

But should I convert it to OOP?  [*because the world is busy with OOP* ]

My code doesn't need any of the feature of OOP [encapsulation, inheritance basically...]!

So what should I do?

And what kind of help I will get if I convert it to OOP ?

Comment: Please keep us informed if you have to alter this project. It would be interesting to know if you are glad you made this decision or regret it.

Comment: You need encapsulation. OO is one way to get it; maybe you have another that works for you, but one way or another you need to control code dependencies.

Comment: How about an anecdote for you: a few years ago I worked on a medium-sized web application written mostly in JavaScript (don't ask). The style of coding was largely procedural. When the project was nearing completion, I found myself dissatisfied with the way the code was written and rewrote a significant portion of it in OOP-JavaScript. This caused a delay in getting the project done, and we ended up doing relatively little maintenance on the project later on. I've always wondered if all of that coding was worth the effort ;-)

Comment: yes it was worth it. keeping the doors of reusability open s always worth it.

Comment: The question is: do you expect further development? Procedural programming is the easiest and fastest approach when you know EXACTLY what you need and it's not going to change. Any change to procedural code will be pain, in OOP it would be much easier.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> My code doesn't need any of the feature of OOP

You have answered your own question - if you don't need OOP **in this case** and your project is working then don't convert it.

However, you should look at using OOP for your *next* project - but only if it's appropriate.

There's nothing intrinsically wrong with procedural programming - as long as it's used in the appropriate place.

Comment: +1 of agree "you should look at using OOP for your next project".

Comment: +1 yes, if it's working correctly don't fix it.

Comment: I would say, if it is working correctly now, don't change it, but you never know what the next feature request is going to be.

Comment: "you should look at using OOP for your next project", but don't use it unless it makes sense.  Some things are better written procedurally, some are better fits for OOP.  Use whatever is appropriate.

Comment: @TMN - that's implied - I should make it explicit.

Answer (score 17):

No and not just because you don't need OOP.

If your program is already finished and working satisfactory then over 90% of the time it it is a wast of time to rewrite finished code for whatever reason.

OOP is not all powerful there are plenty of places where OOP should not be used so don't just use it because OOP is the trend.

Comment: By "finished code" do you mean it works?

Comment: @eff O yes sir ! it's perfect :)

Comment: He said he has finished the project and it is running perfectly. To me this means that it is either ready to deliver to the customer or has been delivered to the customer assuming there is one. By finished I mean tested and ready to ship, of course if major bugs appear a rewrite may come into play.

Comment: Please elaborate on the "plenty of places where OOP should not be used".

Comment: @Falcon Small projects for one - the oop structure can take a long time to implement properly and add complexity that is not necessary. When code is not reused - I know eventual you will reuse almost everything you have done but if it is just a quick program to solve a problem it again ads time and complexity. When you are working on you own - if no one else needs to understand your code then these is no need to take time to make it a more readable style (can be seen as a personal preference more than a fact).

Comment: @Skeith I disagree, I think the boilerplate code needed for OOP only adds a negligble amount of time. I also think that well designed OOP is less complex than a functional equivalent procedural design and easier to extend and maintain, even for small programs. Using your logic, you'll inevitably end up with poorly written software that grows over time and that some poor fellow has a hard time to maintain in the future. I've seen such software often enough. There's little to no benefit in preferring a procedural approach over an OOP approach, even for small projects.

Comment: @Falcon The point was that the project wouldn't grow over time as it was a simple program. I agree that long term scalable projects benefit from being oop right from the start but not all projects fit that spec.

Comment: @Falcon, no matter how well designed your OOP code is, but if the problem domain itself is poorly mapped to OO model, your OOP design is bound to be crappy. There are loads of problem domains which *should never be expressed in terms of OOP*.

Answer (score 9):

My general take on paradigms (and why none of the three major paradigms is the right way or the wrong way to program):

Procedural programming is good when you have a problem that's simple at a high level (though it may be complex at a low level) and want to write correspondingly simple, linear code.  It's arguably easier to write and understand than OO and functional if the problem isn't in need of strong decoupling anywhere.  Examples:  Numerics code, most small scrips, most small subproblems once you've broken things down using OO or functional.

Object oriented code is good when you need to strongly decouple concerns because you may have more than one implementation of some concerns.  Example:  Most large business software.  You may, for example, want to strongly decouple business logic from presentation logic because they probably will need to change independently.

Functional-style programming is good when you need strong separation of mechanism from policy.  Having a mechanism function that accepts a policy function is a nice pattern.  (I learned about it by looking at the D programming language's [std.algorithm module](http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_algorithm.html).)  Abstracting away mutable state at the boundary between policy and mechanism code generally makes the API easier to reason about.  If mutable state is used privately in either, this is an implementation detail.  Functional programming's other strength is concurrency, for self-evident reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer describing each type of programming paradigm and providing examples of when/how to use them.

Answer (score 7):

*Code* never "needs OOP". It's programmers, insofar as they are able to think in different modes, who envision that this or that particular problem "needs" $PARADIGM or is best solved that way.

It is often the case that programmers who only know one paradigm think that their paradigm is the greatest. One size fits all, and we all must sleep in Procrustes' bed, if this or that is currently fashionable.

Answer (score 5):

You should only convert your project to OOP if there is a clear indication of need for OOP.
Possible scenarios in which this may occur are (among others) :

- scaling up the project
- adding more developers to the team

and even in these scenarios it may still not be necessary to convert your project to OOP.

Comment: Good point, but can you tell me why it will be problem to scale up the project or adding more developer in the team if it's a procedural code ?

Comment: Scaling up the project may involve adding complex relational structures to the application model, in which case, it may become profitable to switch to OOP.
If the application scales up bit by bit, and would in the long run turn out to be easier to realise or understand in OOP, new developers may 'catch up' faster, if the code is OOP.
Leaving behind a legacy of non-OO code may turn out to be a problem later on when the project gets bigger.
one more of those cases where 'things are the way they are because they got that way'

Comment: this is exactly what came to my mind when i read the question. he says he has written 13 K lines of code. i hope it wont be wasted by using only once. and if it has to be reused then oop would become a must. otherwise it would become a nightmare for the new developers

Answer (score 4):

Both can be good, both can be bad. But retrofitting one to look like the other is never a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you think back to why OO was invented, you'll see that you don't *need* OOP at all, but sometimes it makes your life a lot easier.

Back in the days of C coding, a very large program could become quite messy and difficult to keep working with. So they invented ways of splitting it up into modular chunks. OOP takes this approach and makes it even more modular, putting data with those chunks of program logic so they are even more separated from the rest of the code.

This allows you to write bigger and bigger programs, safe that you've changed your huge elephant of a task into a hundred mice-sized tasks instead. The added bonus is that you can take some of these 'mice' and reuse them in other programs!

Of course, the real world is not quite like that, and object reuse never quite caught on in the way it was intended, but it doesn't mean it's a useless paradigm.

What is useless is an over-reliance on either style of coding. Anyone who does OO with a thousand tiny, insignificant classes is not really doing it right - they're making a maintenance nightmare for themselves (or someone else). Anyone writing a procedural application that is only 3 functions is also making life hard. The best way is the middlle ground, large-ish objects (sometimes called components which is where we looked to be going once upon a time) that can provide a fair amount of stand-alone code and data that is much more likely to be reused in isolation from the rest of your app.

My advice for next time: try writing your usual procedural code, but create a single object of your main data structure. See how you find that working with it is easier than passing data around from function to function.

Answer (score 0):

> My code doesn't need any of the feature of OOP [encapsulation, inheritance basically...]!

How do you know that?

Do you need to maintain this project? Are there any new features planned? 
There will be other people who will be developing with you?
Did you repeat yourself? Is the code hard to grasp?

If the answer is "yes", than maybe you should start thinking about setting up an OOP skeleton and going this way.